# Fetch specific value in JSON using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this...

```
{
"success": true,
"num_items": 6104,
"items": [
    {
        "market_name": "\u2605 Bayonet",
        "market_hash_name": "\u2605 Bayonet",
        "icon_url": "\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQh5hlcX0nvUOGsx8DdQBJjIAVHubSaKQZ53P3NZXMXvYmykdLSxqWkZ7-HkjMIvpIj3u2Y84733gzh_RU_MG_zIYLEdQ45fxiOrdJh0ExF",
        "name_color": "8650AC",
        "quality_color": "EB4B4B"
    },
    {
        "market_name": "\u2605 Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred)",
        "market_hash_name": "\u2605 Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred)",
        "icon_url": "\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpotLu8JAllx8zJYAJA4MmzkL-DkvbiKvXTkzNVucNzj7mX9tWk21Xkr0JvN231JYGcdA47NF3Y81Hoxebs1sftot2XnmcyW1u0",
        "name_color": "8650AC",
        "quality_color": "EB4B4B"
    },
    // etc ...
]
```

I have a bunch of so called items, and I want to get the `quality_color` by ONLY knowing the `market_hash_name`. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: Loop through all the items, for each item check if the `market_hash_name` matches the one you know. If so, return/output the `quality_color` and break out of your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will need to do is the following:

1. Decode your JSON file [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This will allow your JSON to be accessable in an associative array.
2. Use a for loop or a foreach loop to go through each array in the 'items' array, comparing the market_hash_name with your user's(?) input then take the value of the quality_color of that array.

EDIT: You made a good attempt at the answer, so here's my working solution to your problem. From the small snippet of code you have shown me the problem is that you aren't making the json_decode an associative array but are calling the array as if it was one. Instead of `json_decode($JSONString)` it should be `json_decode($JSONString, true)`

```
<?php

 $JSONin = '{
  "success": true,
  "num_items": 6104,
  "items": [
    {
      "market_name": "★ Bayonet",
      "market_hash_name": "★ Bayonet",
      "icon_url": "//steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQh5hlcX0nvUOGsx8DdQBJjIAVHubSaKQZ53P3NZXMXvYmykdLSxqWkZ7-HkjMIvpIj3u2Y84733gzh_RU_MG_zIYLEdQ45fxiOrdJh0ExF",
      "name_color": "8650AC",
      "quality_color": "EB4B4B"
    },
    {
      "market_name": "★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred)",
      "market_hash_name": "★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred)",
      "icon_url": "//steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpotLu8JAllx8zJYAJA4MmzkL-DkvbiKvXTkzNVucNzj7mX9tWk21Xkr0JvN231JYGcdA47NF3Y81Hoxebs1sftot2XnmcyW1u0",
      "name_color": "8650AC",
      "quality_color": "EB4B4B"
    }
  ]
}';

 $JSON = json_decode($JSONin, true);

 $searched_market_hash_name = "★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Battle-Scarred)";

 foreach ($JSON['items'] as $item)
     {
     if ($searched_market_hash_name == $item['market_hash_name'])
         {
         echo "found! quality color is " . $item['quality_color'];
         }
     }
```

Comment: Got it working finally. Thanks for your answer! Appreciated.

Comment: No problem mate glad to help.